# finite difference method for derivative boundary condtioin in matlab

Tags: matlab, pde

I tried this code to solve the finite difference partial differential equation with derivative boundary condition where trying to enter the boundary condition for the system in the if statement but its not working while the function is 
     partial (T)/partial (t) = partial ^2(T)/partial ^2(x) + 100*sin(pi*x)

```
clear all
clc
n=40; %number of division for x 
 j=500;
dx=0.25;
dt=0.025;
x=0:dx:5;
alpha=0.4;
for j=1:dt:500;
     for i=1:dx:n+1;  
         T=ones(i+1,j)
         T(:,0)=0 %intial condition 
         T(n+1,j+1)=T(n+1,j)+(2*dt/dx^2)*(T(n,j)-(T(n+1,j)*
(1+dx))+10*dx)%for the derivative boundary condition at N+1  
         T(2,j+1)=  T(0,j+1)+(2*dx)*(T(1,j+1)-10)    %for the second 
derivative  boundary condition 
     T(i,j+1)=T(i,j)+(dt/dx^2)*(T(i-1,j)-2*T(i,j)+T(i+1,j))+100*sin(pi*x)*dt %the nodal equation
     end
 end
```

Comment: Which code is there?

Comment: '{
clear all
clc
 n=40; %number of division for x 
 j=500;
 dx=0.25;
 dt=0.025;
 x=0:dx:5;
 alpha=0.4;
 for j=1:dt:500;
     for i=1:dx:n+1;  
         T=ones(i+1,j)
         T(:,0)=0 %intial condition 
         T(n+1,j+1)=T(n+1,j)+(2*dt/dx^2)*(T(n,j)-(T(n+1,j)*(1+dx))+10*dx)%for the derivative boundary condition at N+1  
         T(2,j+1)=  T(0,j+1)+(2*dx)*(T(1,j+1)-10)    %for the second derivative boundary condition 
         T(i,j+1)=T(i,j)+(dt/dx^2)*(T(i-1,j)-2*T(i,j)+T(i+1,j))+100*sin(pi*x)*dt %the nodal equation
         end
     end
}'

Comment: XL=0
     Xr=10
     i=40
     tf=12.5
      j=500
     dx=Xr/i
     dt=tf/j
     x=XL:dx:Xr
     k=1
     alpha=k*dt/dx^2
     T=zeros(j,i+1)
     T(1,:)=0
     for j=1:dt:500
          for n=1:dx:i+1
              if j==1
                 T=0
              elseif n==i+1
                  T(n+1,j+1)=T(n+1,j)+(2*dt/dx^(2))*(T(n,j)-T(n+1,j)*
    (1+dx)+10*dx)+100*sin(pi*x)*dt
              elseif n==1
                  T(2,j+1)=T(0,j+1)+2*dx*(T(1,j+1)-10)
         else
             T(n,j+1)=T(n,j)+(dt/dx^2)*(T(n-1,j)-2*T(n,j)+T(n+1,j))+100*sin(pi*x)*dt